# word guessing game in python

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm trying to create a guessing game that prompts the user for a word, then prompts for letter guesses. I was having trouble with my code - my expected output was " guess 'not found'" if the letter guess was not in the word, but no matter the guess, the output continues to be " guess 'found'".
Here's my original code:

```
word = input('Enter a guess word: ')
while True:
        guess = input('Enter a guess letter: ')
        for word in guess:
                if guess in word:
                        print('\t>', guess, 'found')
                else:
                        print('\t>', guess, 'not found')
```

for example if the user inputs 'hello' as the word and 'p' as the guess, it will still print '> p found'.
Later, I was just fooling around and it worked? Firstly, when I tried to apply this to my original code, it didn't work (the problem remained, just that the output continuously returned 'not found' instead). Secondly, I do not understand how this ended up working...
This is the working(?) code:

```
for x in 'word':
        pass
for word in x:
        if 'p' in word:
                print(':)')
        else:
                print(':(')
```

attempt to apply to original code:

```
word = input('Enter a guess word: ')
while True:
        guess = input('Enter a guess letter: ')
        for x in word:
                pass
        for word in x:
                if guess in word:
                        print('\t>', guess, 'found')
                else:
                        print('\t>', guess, 'not found')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be careful when naming your variables. You first declare `word` as your target but then use `word` again to represent each character of `guess`.

Let's say my guess word is *test* and my guess is *a*.

Since you wrote `for word in guess`, `word` is now *a*. That is why `if word in guess` will always return `True`, because *a* is indeed in *a*.

Here is how to fix it:

```
word = input('Enter a guess word: ')
while True:
        guess = input('Enter a guess letter: ')
        for x in guess: # or any other variable name besides "word"
                if x in word:
                        print('\t>', guess, 'found')
                else:
                        print('\t>', guess, 'not found')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the value of the word variable with the following line:

```
 for word in guess:
```

change the variable name

Answer (score 0):

You are basically over writing the variable `word` with the letter when you iterate over the loop. Also, you need to iterate over `word` and not `guess`:

```
word = input('Enter a guess word: ')
while True:
        guess = input('Enter a guess letter: ')
        for words in word:
                
                if guess==words:
                        print('\t>', guess, 'found')
                        break
                else:
                        print('\t>', guess, 'not found')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you first defined `word` as a variable and then stored the input in it.

```
word = input('Enter a guess word: ')
```

Then, you tried to execute the `while loop` there, you're taking the input letter in `guess`:

```
guess = input('Enter a guess letter: ')
```

The **problem begins** from the next line, inside this loop:

```
for word in guess:
        if guess in word:
                print('\t>', guess, 'found')
        else:
                print('\t>', guess, 'not found')
```

In the loop, the iteration condition is `for word in guess`, which considers `word` as a local item inside the loop containing each element of the `guess` per iteration.

In next line, the if condition checks `if guess in word`, which means, you're checking if the `guess` is in the `word`, but this `word` is nothing but the `word` introduced in `for loop`. So, technically you've overwritten the `actual word` introduced at the beginning, with the letters from the guess input.

As the `guess` from input and the `word` in `guess` are same, this condition is satisfied for the letter `p`. Hence you're getting the `p found` as the result.

But it should be changed too, take each `letter` from `guess`, and check whether the `letter` is in `word`. Just change the name of the variable `word` in the condition `for word in guess` to something like `for letter in guess`. Also change `if guess in word` to `if letter in word`, while you're running a loop `for letter in guess`. And it'll work properly:

```
word = input('Enter a guess word: ')
while True:
    guess = input('Enter a guess letter: ')
    for letter in guess:
            if letter in word:
                    print('\t>', guess, 'found')
            else:
                    print('\t>', guess, 'not found')
```